# Error using lodash in angular2

Tags: angular, lodash, angular-cli

I'm trying to use `lodash` in `angular 2.4.0`

`angular-cli` : `"@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.4",`

Tried to import like this
`import * as _ from 'lodash';`

Also tried

```
npm install --save lodash

npm install --save @types/lodash
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "travelz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.37",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

getting these errors:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/travelz/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8599,32): ',' expected.)
C:/xampp/htdocs/travelz/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8602,14): ']' expected.)
C:/xampp/htdocs/travelz/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8602,15): ';' expected.)
C:/xampp/htdocs/travelz/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8605,26): ',' expected.)
C:/xampp/htdocs/travelz/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8605,42): '(' expected.)
C:/xampp/htdocs/travelz/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8605,61): ',' expected.)
C:/xampp/htdocs/travelz/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8605,66): ')' expected.)
C:/xampp/htdocs/travelz/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8607,15): ';' expected.)
C:/xampp/htdocs/travelz/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8607,25): Declaration or statement expected.)
C:/xampp/htdocs/travelz/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8608,23): ')' expected.)
C:/xampp/htdocs/travelz/node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts (8608,46): '(' expected.)
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Try this  https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/15/angular2-import-lodash-into-angular2-application-using-typescript/, Hope it's help

Comment: @Dr.Tricker it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

need to install the lodash under @types.

```
$ npm install --save lodash

$ npm install --save @types/lodash
```

Then import it like this

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

Comment: tried but it is giving different errors now

Comment: @NikhilRadadiyawhat is the error  ?

Comment: @sachilaranawaka updated question, please check

Comment: @RahulSingh updated question please check